# I'm just curious about this JS I found

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashtag

I found this Javascript somewhere and want to learn. Therefore, I'll just give questions for what I don't know.

1) I wonder why there's hashtag to the builder variable.

```
 (function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
   var builder = $('#builder');
```

2) Seems like the builder written down there has got sth to do with #builder...

```
 /**
    * Gets the json for the form in the embedded builder.
    *
    * @return string the form's json.
    */
 var getFormDocument = function() {
     if (document.getElementById('builder').contentWindow.getFormDocument == null) {
        return '{}';
     }

     return document.getElementById('builder').contentWindow.getFormDocument();
   };
```

3) Again, a hash tag here. Is it from the css?

```
     /**
        * Adjusts the builder's height to the window.
        */

   var resizer = function() {
     var w = $(window).height(),
       h = $('header').height(),
       t = $('#top-row').height(),
       p = 12, // top padding
       o = (w - h - t - p) + 'px';

      builder.css('height', o);
  };
```

4) Is .js-form-document one of JQuery's function?

```
/**
   * Called when the user is done building their form.
   */
  var clickedSave = false;
  var save = function() {
      clickedSave = true;
      jQuery('.js-form-document').val(getFormDocument());
      jQuery('#builderModal_signup').reveal();

  };
```

5) Why there's TODO saying iframe goes bonkers? And after the user save the form, how does this js code get connected to database?

```
/**
   * Adds listeners for the embedded builder and keeps the
   * builder properly positioned.
   */
  var init = function() {

    // TODO: iframe width at 100% goes bonkers.
    var width  = $($('div.twelve.columns')[0]).width();
    builder.css('display', 'block');
    builder.css('width', width + 'px');

    $('.js-save').click(save);
  };



 var hasFields = function() {
    var formDocument = JSON.parse(getFormDocument());
    if (formDocument.fields == null) {
      return false;
    }

    var sections = formDocument.fields;

    if (sections.length === 0 || sections[0].fields.length === 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  };
```

6) Don't get what the hash tag here means...

```
/*
   * Triggers a call to action for the user
   */
  var firstCallout = function() {
    if (clickedSave) {
      return;
    }

    if (!hasFields()) {
        jQuery('#builderModal_noFields').reveal();
    } else {
        jQuery('#builderModal_hasFields').reveal();
    }
  };


 init();

  setTimeout(function(){firstCallout();}, 30000);
  setInterval(function() {
      var onClass = $('.js-save').attr('data-on-class');
      if (onClass === '') {
        onClass = 'green';
      }

      if (hasFields()) {
        $('.js-save').removeClass('gray').addClass(onClass);
      } else {
        $('.js-save').removeClass(onClass).addClass('gray');
      }
  }, 1000); 

});
})(jQuery);

var lastHeight = 0;
function resizeBuilder() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('builder');
    var padding = 20;
    var height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;

    //chrome counts padding in scroll height and creates never ending height
    if (Math.abs(height - lastHeight) <= padding) {
        return;
    }

    height += padding;

    if (height < 400) {
        height = 400;
    }

    iframe.height = height + 'px';
    lastHeight = height;
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: The answer to almost all of those is "it's a jQuery selector". http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Comment: You can start learning jQuery. It will answer all your questions.

Comment: Please don't dump a bunch of random code you don't understand into a post here and ask for explanations. That is not what this site is about.

Answer (score 0):

Well, clearly you lack basic knowledge of ***jQuery***.
Hashes stand for DOM elements IDs' selectors, and dots stand for classes selectors.
About the "TODO" - this looks like the developer's comment after he had enough with iframes. Why it goes nuts on 100% ? no clue.

The form is being processed by some server-side script/code that the client-side script communicates with (read more about *AJAX* ).

Hope that's clarifies a bit,
Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Is not a "hashtag" is a CSS selector, he is selecting the object by the id "builder"

In CSS you can select things using this syntax.

- "#" by id
- "." by class
- "sometag", with no special caracter it means you are selecting a tag (or a bunch of them).

And using a tag or a class or a id you can do inside selection using properties like

"div[name=mydiv]".

Hope it helps.